# How to declare global variables without using window object in sapui5

Tags: javascript, global-variables, sapui5

I have followed many examples and none are getting me a result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls share what you have tried and what was the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       onInit : function(){
           $.sap.myVar = "console this";
       },

       someFunction : function(){
           console.log($.sap.myVar);
       }
```

//By declaring like this you can access the variable through out the application

Answer (score -2):

Did you try with "this".
This solution is build in SAP WEB IDE. Modify it, if you are using any other platform.

Code in View

```
<Button text="Click to display global variable" press="onDisplay"></Button>
```

Code in Controller

```
    onInit:function()
    {
        this.value = "Welcome New user!";   //global variable
    },
    onDisplay:function()
    {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show(this.value);
    }
```

Revert if any doubt.

Thanks
Kiran Israni